# What does "(measure) almost-every (random variable)" mean?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-process

I encountered [here](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Estevel/565/lectures/5d%20MCMC.pdf) the following definition of recurrence for continuous-state-space Markov chains:

> For every measurable set $B$ with $\phi(B)>0$,
> $$\mathbf P(X_1,X_2,\ldots\in B\text{ i.o.}|X_0) > 0$$
> for all $X_0$, and
> $$\mathbf P(X_1,X_2,\ldots\in B\text{ i.o.}|X_0) = 1$$
> for $\phi$ almost-every $X_0$.

Apparently, $\phi$ is a measure, and $X_0,X_1,\ldots$ are random variables. What does "$\phi$ almost-every $X_0$" mean?

Comment: you should first understand what a markov chain is. to this end, read section 5.2 of durrett's pte

Comment: Presumably the start of the chain $X_0$ is not random, as opposed to the other $X_i\,.$